# How to upgrade Sencha ExtJS6 to ExtJS7

Tags: extjs, extjs6-classic

How can one upgrade Sencha ExtJS v6.2.0.103 to ExtJS v7. I do see `Upgrade Guide` but it does not mention anything

https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.0.0/guides/whats_new/api_diffs/700_classic_diff.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sencha's upgrade page could be better...

Here's a user who figured it out

https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?323886-How-to-upgrade-your-workspace-to-latest-Cmd-and-ExtJS

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Sencha's npm (ExtGen) tooling, you can upgrade your existing application using the [`ext-movetolatest`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.0.0/guides/using_systems/using_npm/extmovetolatest.html) utility. This will take of the necessary configuration updates to package.json, webpack.config.js, app.json, etc.

You can migrate your project from a standard ExtJS + Sencha Cmd application to an ExtGen application using [`ext-gen migrate`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.0.0/guides/using_systems/using_npm/npm_migrate.html)

Comment: For Sencha Cmd, follow [this](https://docs.sencha.com/cmd/7.0.0/guides/cmd_upgrade.html) guide! `sencha app upgrade /path/to/downloaded/sdk` is pretty straightforward